# Installed Primary IDE Device (HDD) - not recognized

Tags: hard-drive, ide

After I installed Xubuntu 16.4.2.  Don't see primary IDE HDD in BIOS, but system runs.  Cable problem?  Do I need to tell the machine to mount the drive?  Strange that it is there and working, but not seen in BIOS ?

Comment: There is no way that just installing Ubuntu prevents the BIOS from detecting the drive. Maybe the cable came loose, the PSU is failing, or the HDD just kicked the bucket?

Comment: It just hit me that I probably need to change the jumpers to Master setting.  Duh!  Total beginner mistake.  At least I think that will do the trick.  Thank you.

Comment: If that was the case, please enter and answer and check the answer as final answer, so the question does not remain open. Thx